# Python issue with string conversion

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
[[30, '10', '10', '10'], [27, '10', '10', '7'], [27, '9', '8', '10'], [25, '9', '9', '7'], [25, '7', '10', '8'], [25, '8', '10', '7'], [24, '7', '10', '7'], [24, '8', '9', '7'], [24, '6', '10', '8'], [24, '4', '10', '10'], [24, '9', '10', '5'], [24, '7', '7', '10'], [24, '10', '10', '4'], [23, '3', '10', '10'], [23, '6', '9', '8'], [23, '8', '5', '10'], [23, '9', '8', '6'], [23, '8', '7', '8'], [22, '10', '3', '9'], [22, '3', '10', '9'], [22, '4', '8', '10'], [22, '8', '6', '8'], [22, '10', '10', '2'], [21, '9', '4', '8'], [21, '8', '4', '9'], [21, '6', '6', '9'], [21, '6', '10', '5'], [21, '8', '7', '6'], [21, '3', '9', '9'], [20, '7', '7', '6'], [20, '10', '7', '3'], [20, '10', '8', '2']]
```

I want to read each value and write to a file. I am having an issue converting the first value to a string

Here is my code:

```
with open('problem2.txt', 'w') as writer:
for list in sortedLines:
    string=''
    for i in list:
        if list.index(i) == 0:
            string = str(i) + ": "
            print(type(i))
        else:
            string= string + " " + i
    writer.writelines(string+"\n")
```

The `type(i)` returns `<int>`.  I get the following error - `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Please post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**. Don't use built-ins such as `list`, `str` etc as variable names.

Comment: Why should `i` not be an `int`? Nothing in your code modifies `i`.

Comment: You can just say `list[0] = str(list[0])`.  No need for the enumerating and searching.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) and let Python worry about the conversion:

```py
for line in sortedLines
  string = f'{line[0]}: {" ".join(line[1:]}\n' 
  writer.writelines(string)
```

This should produce lines of the format:

```
30: 10 10 10
27: 10 10 7
27: 9 8 10
25: 9 9 7
25: 7 10 8
```

Comment: Missing `f` prefix for f-string. Also, preferably without the variable shadowing of `list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked.

Comment: @jamrod: should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 main issue that I could find: you have called 'list' in your range. This is already a built-in name, and you are overriding it. Instead, I suggest calling it `line`.

This worked for me:

```
with open('problem2.txt', 'w') as writer:
    for line in sortedLines:
        string = str(line[0]) + ": "
        for i in line[1:]:
            string += " " + i
        writer.writelines(string + "\n")
```

I removed the if-else, just because it was unnecessary and the same effect could be achieved when defining the string.